# ive done a code that changes ownership and transfer the balance of the old owner to the new one but it does not seem to work

Tags: blockchain, solidity

```
// contracts/transferownership.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";


contract transferownership is ERC20, Ownable  {

uint256 lastpresence;
uint256 amount = balanceOf(msg.sender);
constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20("interorm", "intr") {
    _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
}

function presence() public onlyOwner {
    lastpresence = block.timestamp;
}

function changeOwnership(address newowner) public {
    require(lastpresence < block.timestamp - 356 days);
    transfer(newowner, amount);
    _transferOwnership(newowner);
    lastpresence = block.timestamp;

    
}
```

}

//The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Reason provided by the contract: "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance".
Debug the transaction to get more information.

//basically the program should transfer the whole amount of money
and then change ownership but im getting this error
everytime i call the changeownership function

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, simply declare the amount variable in the `changeOwnership` function. That is before you call the `transfer` method.

```
  uint256 amount = balanceOf(msg.sender);
  transfer(newowner, amount);
```

Ensure that you set the `changeOwnership` function as payable.

```
  function changeOwnership(address newowner) payable public {
```

**Explanation:** When you debug the function, the way you have it originally, you will find that the `value=0`, this is because the `amount` declaration in the global variable is not called in the stack when the `transfer` method is called.

To make the `amount` available in the call stack, you will have to parse it in the function.

Comment: even without the amount variable for example: transfer(newowner, 1)     it is still not working and giving the error of exceeding the balance

Comment: Edit: its working the first time i change ownership with all its value but the second time from that address to a different address it fails.  could the cause be the enviroment im using "remix"